# 2 variable, 2 valued function $f(x_1,\,x_2)=(x_1,\,x_2)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Assume that $f(x_1,x_2)=(f_1(x_1,x_2),f_2(x_1,x_2))$ with $f(0,0)=(0,0)$,
\begin{align*}
{\partial f_1\over \partial u_1}(0,0) & ={\partial f_2\over \partial u_2}(0,0)=1\\[2mm]
{\partial f_1\over \partial u_2}(0,0) & ={\partial f_2\over \partial u_1}(0,0)=0
\end{align*}

I think that $f(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_2)$, but how can I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not prove it ! Let $a,b$ differentiable functions of one real variable with

$a(0)=b(0)=0$, $a'(0)=1$ and $b'(0)=1.$

Then the function $f(x_1,x_2)=(a(x_1),b(x_2))$ has the desired properties.

Example: $a(t)=b(t)= \sin t$.

Comment: Oh..i think i made mistake. actually i was proving that f is orientation preserving isometry iff it is a rigid motion. what if f is an isometry then?